# How to install dask-jobqueue on a HPC

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask, hpc, job-queue

I am trying to use dask-jobqueue on a high performing computer (HPC).

Following the documentation on dask-jobqueue [here](https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/install.html), I am trying to install dask-jobqueue on an instance of a Jupyter Notebook in the HPC with the following code:

```
install dask-jobqueue -c conda-forge
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-10-cad837f248c1>", line 1
    install dask-jobqueue -c conda-forge
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have attached a screenshot here:
[image: dask]

I am not sure what I did wrong and what do I do now? Would really appreciate any help.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to install dask-jobqueue from the conda-forge repository using `conda` as stated in the [docs](https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/install.html). But then you should adhere to the full command with the correct syntax:

```
!conda install dask-jobqueue -c conda-forge -y
```

Notice the leading `!` to execute command line statements directly from the notebook. I also added the `-y` option of conda to automatically approve the installation of conda packages within a Jupyter notebook.

I am assuming the conda environment is installed on the computer. Otherwise, you should use the alternative with `pip`:

```
!pip install dask-jobqueue --upgrade
```

Comment: Many thanks @afsharov, this worked! Silly me, I tend to forget there should be an exclamation mark at the front.